# mySQL - Wrap Around Numbers

Tags: mysql, database

I have a grid that goes from 0,0 to 799,799 (800x800 blocks).  The issue I'm having, I can't get my head working on this, an guidance or hint of help would be great.  I can get the result as long it's inside the stated grid, but when it comes to wrap around the grid, it won't give me results.

ie (this will give me result with no problem):

```
SELECT * FROM map WHERE ((xaxis >= 0 AND xaxis <= 10) AND (yaxis >= 0 AND yaxis <= 10))
```

if i tried (wrap around grid):

```
SELECT * FROM map WHERE ((xaxis >= 795 AND xaxis <= 10) AND (yaxis >= 795 AND yaxis <= 10))
```

it will not give me any error or result, how would I go about fixing that?  Any guidance or pointing to right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query:

```
SELECT * FROM map WHERE ((xaxis >= 795 AND xaxis <= 10) AND (yaxis >= 795 AND yaxis <= 10))
```

won't give you any results because xaxis cannot be >= 795 and <= 10 (likewise yaxis).

To wrap around, you need to use the remainder or modulus function - something like:

```
SELECT * FROM map WHERE ((MOD(799,xaxis-1)>0 AND xaxis <= 10) AND (MOD(799,yaxis-1)>0 AND yaxis <= 10))
```

Comment: ahhh makes perfect sense!  I'll give that a shot, yeah I just didn't think of Gtr/Less than 799 and 0  doh me haha, will get back to ya on that.. Many thanks for pointing to the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer by the help of someone elsewhere, figure I put in here so someone could benefit this:

```
$input_left_x     = (($XCoord - $Miles + 800) % 800);
$input_right_x    = (($XCoord + $Miles) % 800);
$input_left_y     = (($YCoord - $Miles + 800) % 800);
$input_right_y    = (($YCoord + $Miles) % 800);

SELECT * FROM map
WHERE MOD( xaxis - COALESCE(".$input_left_x." , 0) + 800 , 800 )
BETWEEN 0 AND MOD( COALESCE(".$input_right_x." , 799) - COALESCE(".$input_left_x." , 0) + 800 , 800 )
AND MOD( yaxis - COALESCE(".$input_left_y." , 0) + 800 , 800 )
BETWEEN 0 AND MOD( COALESCE(".$input_right_y." , 799) - COALESCE(".$input_left_y." , 0) + 800 , 800 )
```

Comment: 800 is basically the size of the said map.  From that, it'll check the database of xaxis and yaxis to see if it's within the defined $Miles, $XCoord/$YCoord provided by user requesting information.